# Assign Dropdown equal to my label and how to adjust dropdown width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have designed a web with label and dropdown in MVC. I want to adjust the width of the dropdown box, and I want my dropdown to be displayed after my colon in the following design:

```
Emp Type     : (I want Dropdown here).
```

[image: but my dropdown comes below as shown in image]

The code used is below:

```
<span> Emp Type</span>:
 @Html.DropDownList("EmpType1", new SelectList(@ViewBag.EmplayeeTypeViewBag, "Key", "Value"),new { @class = "form-control" })
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is a job for CSS. As such, you'll need to post your rendered HTML, and any relevant CSS.

Comment: Try using CSS `display: inline-block;` in `span` or `select` class, or wrap it inside a `div` which uses given selector.

Comment: sory ,I can't get you. Which one you want? As I am new to MVC , I am under confusion now..

Comment: Try applying div like this: `<div style="display:inline-block;"><span>...</span>@Html.DropDownListFor(...)</div>` and see if the caption label renders inline with select control.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried , its not working

Comment: Seems that you need to define both `span` and `select` DDLF as inline: `span, select { display:inline-block; }`. Check http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/52VtD/7464/ for how to use `inline-block` with CSS (and to adjust DDLF's width you can use `select { width: # }` (# = number in pixel or percent)).

Comment: I use someother functions to adjust the width,its working. but for the alignment its not working. I tired your css inline code also.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thank you. I tried your <span style="display: inline-block">Dropdown list()</span>.. this one working.